# Build input file cannot be found, IOS build failed code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making an app build, i have some problem making the build. I searched it and found the fix but that was using the flutter.

Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/macbook/Downloads/tram/App/View/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the bug by making copying the code in the file and then delete the file and after creating file again i pasted the code in it and now it is working fine.